# how to simplify a multi-layer "ArrayList"?

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to define many variables of type  `ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>>`

But that looks bad.

What I think of now is to create a class like the following

```
Public class ArrayListMulti{
    ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>> ret;
    public void ArrayListMulti(){
        ret = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>> getTheArrayList(){
        return ret;
    }
}
```

But using this method, every time I want to access the `ret` value, I must call the `getTheArrayList` method.

Is there an easier way?

Thanks in advance ~

Comment: Depends on your use-case. If you are using this as a matrix or a graph/tree, there are dedicated java libraries like commons-math etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `ArrayList`

```java
public class ArrayListMulti extends ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>>{}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to have so deep array list? If so, you should thing about providing convenient API of your `ArrayListMulti` class. For instance, you can add methods like these:

```
public List<List<List<Integer>>> get(int i) {
    return ret.get(i);
}

public List<List<Integer>> get(int i, int j) {
    return ret.get(i).get(j);
}

...
```

and so on. (Don't forget to check nested lists for null.)

And one small tip: use a interface, not class when you define a class field (in your case `List<List<List<List>>>> ret`. It will make your code more robust if you want to change implementation of `List` interface (e.g. replace `ArrayList` to `LinkedList`).

Answer (score 0):

use multidimensional array like 3D array or more

Comment: int [ ] [ ] [ ] arr = new int [10][4][3];